# DataWedge Reg Settings on Mobile Computers

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, scanning, datawedge

I am using Avalanche MDM to manage a number of older devices. I am looking for the registry path for DataWedge being used on Motorola 9090, 9190, and 9200.

The two i cannot find are the Interchar delay and I want to diasble Send as Events.

This should allow the scanner to receive the registry setting when reporting back to our MDM server after being stuck in a drawer, not charged, etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You may want to try expanding your tags. As it is it's posted to a tag with 0 followers, so it may not get seen.

Comment: When I used to need to do similar tasks I would just export the registry from the device using Pocket Controller Pro (https://www.soti.net/products/pocket-controller/) or a similar tool.  You can then either search the registry or make a config change and compare the registry after the change to find the setting.